# Populate UITableView from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Having an issue where the array values do not display in my tableview cells, but can be printed out correctly with NSLog. Thanks in advance for your help!

TableViewCell .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

TableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imagesArray;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *namesArray;

@end
```

TableViewController.m

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize primaryWeaponNames = _primaryWeaponNames;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self setupArrays];

}

- (void)setupArrays {

    _namesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"NAME1", @"NAME2", @"NAME3"
                            nil];


    self.imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"IMG1", @"IMG2", @"IMG3"
                            nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return _namesArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";

TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"%@", _namesArray[indexPath.row]);

cell.image.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: did you implement the `UITableViewDataSource` methods?

Comment: Yes its in the header file

Comment: What have you done to debug it?  Are your dataSource methods being called?  What value does `numberOfRownInSection` return?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Put a breakpoint in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method. Is it called? Is `_nameArray` non-nil and does it contain any objects?

Comment: Yes, _nameArray has the correct values. When I print an NSLog it prints correctly. Just doesn't appear in the simulator

Comment: you need to **implement** the methods!

Comment: You can't set the image of your image view with [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] since that array contains strings, not images.

Comment: @rdelmar I haven't had a chance to work with the images, since the labels are working yet.

Comment: @rmaddy the correct numbers of rows are displayed, but they're just blank

Comment: How and where are you making your custom cell? In a storyboard? In a xib?

Comment: In a separate xib file

Comment: You should register the nib then (using 
registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:). Have you done that?

Comment: Where would I do that?

Comment: In viewDidLoad, I'm writing an answer now.

Comment: Ok I tried that, but then it caused the app to crash with an error, "Could not load NIB in bundle"

Comment: Then you either don't have the nib in your bundle, or you didn't implement the method correctly. Edit your question to show what you did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63516/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-seslyn).

Answer (score 0):

When you make the cell in a xib file, you should register the nib in viewDidLoad. Since you didn't do that, the dequeue method will return nil, and you're just creating a default cell (in the if (cell == nil) clause) instead of your custom cell. The default cell doesn't have a nameLabel or image property, so the lines to set the values of those outlets won't do anything.

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Your nib name here" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableViewCell];
```

Comment: Ok, the error is - '[<NSObject 0x7f869b8306a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.'

Comment: I'm taking out all the image stuff so I'm just working with the label

Answer (score -2):

In your `TableViewController` class, you need to include

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.datasource = self;
```

in your `viewDidLoad` method. Or you can do this in interface builder by right click dragging the table view in your tableview controller to file's owner and setting delegate, then repeat for datasource

Comment: added those, still nothing

Comment: No, you do not. The OP is using a UITableViewController which is set as the data source and delegate by default.

Comment: It was just a thought. @Seslyn, when you set a breakpoint in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` does it get called? And stepping through, does it return a cell or nil?